# Pattern.compile null Syntax Exception

Tags: java, regex, string, exception, null

The pattern line keeps throwing null-pointers and I have no idea why. I tried with `Pattern.quote`, but it comes up as:

```
Pattern p: \Q.*(bread){1, 1}.{1, 1}(bread){1, 1}.*\E|java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=\Q.*(bread){1, 1}.{1, 1}(bread){1, 1}.*\E region=0,13 lastmatch=]
```

and this is totally not what it should be. I want to return the string between the two `bread` substrings.

```
public String getSandwich(String str) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(bread){1, 1}(.{1, 1})(bread){1, 1}.*");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

  if (m.find()) {
      return m.group(2);
  } else {
  return "";
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your input string? Format your error message.

Comment: In a regex pattern all characters are significant including spaces, other thing quantifiers like `{n,n}` can be shorten as `{n}` and writing `{1}` is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your pattern:

```
.*(bread){1, 1}(.{1, 1})(bread){1, 1}.*
no space ---^ here -^ and here ---^
```

btw, what's the point of having a quantifier expressed like `{1,1}`?

Test here: http://fiddle.re/y2mxd6

Comment: @AvinashRaj you'll need to escape the curly brace to literally match it

Comment: @AvinashRaj but that's a different flavor of regex; you should refer to this for java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html See here: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: hmm, java uses a different thing.